# Visual Basic - Dropbox update

Tags: vb.net

I have a label1 with the text "1.0.0.0". I want the form on start up to check for an update using dropbox by checking the dropbox link's version and comparing it with the app's current version but I am having some issues running it. This is my code so far:

```
Dim Web As New Net.WebClient
    Dim version As Integer = Web.DownloadString("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ny7brjs7zx1mt89/V.txt")
    If version > CInt(Label6.Text) Then 'Example.: new version: 1.1.0.0, current version: 1.0.0.0 -> downloading update
        Try
            Dim path As String = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/ny7brjs7zx1mt89/V.txt?dl=1" 'The .rar archive
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(path, Application.StartupPath & "/[Update" & version & "]" & "Update.rar")
            MsgBox("An update has been downloaded", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Update")


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("An error has occurred") 'Error message. Can also be msgBox("An error has occurred").
        End Try
    ElseIf System.IO.File.Exists("[Update1100]Update.rar") Then
        MsgBox("You've already downloaded the update!")
        MsgBox("Just search for:" & vbNewLine & "[Update1100]Update .rar")
    ElseIf version = CInt(Label6.Text) Then
        MsgBox("You already have the latest version!")
    Else
    End If
```

[image]

Comment: _I am having some issues_  Which are?  Edit your question with the exact details of the problem

Comment: @Hursey okie, just added a screenshot

Comment: So, the exception tells you exactly what the problem is.  Your trying to store a string in an integer variable.  So you need to decide what is the appropriate action.  That aside, you're  likely not going to get your desired result storing a version number as an int (or any number) Maybe look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Hursey well, I tried so many things but I came to temp solution which basically works fine the only one thing I'm working on is downloading the file in the same folder of the app and replaces old files with the new file:
https://traff.co/m717HwvJ (it might help someone)